# How to insert multi-value properties on GAE-Datastore in Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I can't find how to work with multiple valued properties on go, in my case I have defined the next struct:

```
type trans struct {
    Phone   []string `datastore:"phone"`
    Name    string `datastore:"name,noindex"`
    Manager string `datastore:"manager,noindex"`
    Mail    string `datastore:"email,noindex"`
}
```

but I want Phone to be multivalued and I don't know how to do it :(

What I want to get is to be able to filter on the multivalued property like this:

```
datastore.NewQuery("trans").Filter("phone =", "+33699999999").GetAll(c, &mtrans)
```

but this returns a null from the datastore as if it weren't any entity that matches the filter. But there is an entity that has that phone (among others).

Comment: show some code and specify what's not working

Comment: Added the purpose of the multivalue property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change filter to `"Phone =", ...`